# Change div to span multiple rows when middle row display set to none

Tags: javascript, css

I have three divs that each take up a row like in the below code.

The top row question contains some text that changes over time and can be varying length.

The middle row speech_bubble_middle_bar contains an input bar that sometimes will be displayed, and sometimes will not.

The bottom row speech_bubble_bottom_bar contains some buttons that will always be there.

I need to figure out how to expand the size of question when speech_bubble_middle_bar has display set to none, so I have more space for the text when speech_bubble_middle_bar is not displayed.

I thought I could do that by changing grid-rows from 1/2 to 1/3 to define question as spanning the space that previously was taken up by speech_bubble_middle_bar, and I was going to use JavaScript to switch back and forth as needed when the middle bar is displayed. Unfortunately it's not working, and instead moves speech_bubble_bottom_bar up to occupy the empty space.

This is my relevant code:

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -mo-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #311049;
  font-size: 2vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.screen {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-button {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-button img {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 75%;
  max-width: 75%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.display {
  position: relative;
  height: 86.286%;
  width: 100vw;
}

.speech-bubble {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 60% 20% 20%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 61.8%;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 2em;
  z-index: 10;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.speech-bubble:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 15vw;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 4em solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -2em;
  margin-bottom: -2em;
  z-index: -1;
}

.logo-animation {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  display: none;
}

.logo-animation img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: none;
}

.question {
  grid-rows: 1/2;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 5vh;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  background: green;
}

.question-text {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.speech-bubble-middle-bar {
  grid-rows: 2/3;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  background: red;
}

.input-text {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 2.5em;
  border: 0.25em solid black;
  padding: 1%;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.speech-bubble-bottom-bar {
  grid-rows: 3/4;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.left-button-container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 38.2%;
  left: 0%;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.left-button-container button {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.right-button-container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 38.2%;
  right: 0%;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.right-button-container button {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  background: #311049;
  /*Button Color*/
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-family: hack;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-size: clamp(1rem, 3vw, 2rem);
}

.left-btn:after {
  display: block;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  content: "\2190";
}

.right-btn:after {
  display: block;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  content: "\2192";
}
```

```
    <div id="screen" , class="screen">
        <div id="menu_bar" , class="menu-bar">
            <div id="logo" , class="logo">
                <img src="logo.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="title" , class="title">Title</div>
            <div id="menu_button" , class="menu-button">
                <img src="menu.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="display" , class="display">
            <div id="speech_bubble" , class="speech-bubble">
                <div id="logo_animation" , class="logo-animation"><img src="https://media2.giphy.com/media/E0SE1bDv0sTbCH4p6V/giphy.gif?cid=790b761143fe1cebe2466c26bfb82fc6b178eb7ecad3874e&rid=giphy.gif"/></div>
                <div id="question" class="question resize">
                   <div id="question_text" class="question-text">
                    <span>Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. </span>
                   </div> 
                    </div>
                <div id="speech_bubble_middle_bar" class="speech-bubble-middle-bar">
                    <input type="text" id="input-text" class="input-text" />
                </div>
                <div id="speech_bubble_bottom_bar" class="speech-bubble-bottom-bar">
                    <div id="left" class="left-button-container">
                        <button id="left_button" class="button resize">Wow!</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="right_button_container" class="right-button-container">
                        <button id="right_button" class="button resize">Next</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's a pic showing the problem, the red bar is speech_bubble_middle_bar that I need to be able to remove without speech_bubble_bottom_bar moving up, which is does when I hide the middle row by setting speech_bubble_middle_bar display to none.

[image]

Here's what it looks like with speech_bubble_middle_bar display set to none.

[image]

And here's a FS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/TheNomadicAspie/gmb86ak5/7/

Comment: I have a snippet of code above with the three div elements that are affected. I thought including just the relevant parts would be ideal. Is that not the case?

Comment: Ok I added a minimal working version of the code with the irrelevant elements removed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized a solution to this is just to change the grid-template-rows of .speech-bubble as needed from 60% 20% 20% to 80% 0% 20%

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short sample of code that does what I believe you wanted. It is bare and stripped of style. Just what is required.

Be sure to hit the "toggle" button to see the changes.

```js
function toggle(e){
  if(e){e.stopPropagation();e.preventDefault();}
  var q = document.getElementById("question");
  var a = document.getElementById("answer");
  if (a.classList.contains("hide")){
    a.classList.remove("hide");
    q.classList.remove("questionExpand");
    q.classList.add("questionShort");
  } else {
    a.classList.add("hide");
    q.classList.remove("questionShort");
    q.classList.add("questionExpand");
  }
}
window.onload = function(){
  var b = document.getElementById("toggleAnswer");
  b.addEventListener("click",toggle,false);
}
```

```css
.contain {
  line-height:2em;
  height:7em;
  border:1px solid black;
}
#question {
  overflow:auto;
}
.questionShort {
  height:5em;
}
.questionExpand {
  height:7em;
}
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
<div id="question" class="questionExpand">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<div id="answer" class="hide"><input type="text" /></div>
</div>
<div class="buttons"><button id="toggleAnswer" class="butLeft">Toggle</button></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, so looking at your code it seems the main thing I need is to change the height of the div. The problem is when changing the height to 0%, I can see the div is top aligned which keeps me from being able to see the question text when it overflows.

I know the way to fix that is using absolute positioning within a relatively positioned div,  but when I add position: absolute; height: 0%; bottom: 0; to text, it pushes the div below speech_bubble_bottom_bar and creates a huge gap.

https://imgur.com/a/NBidqjL

Comment: My issue isn't being unable to show and hide the div, it's that when I do it disrupts the rest of my CSS formatting.